# How to not monitor traffic on a single page but the rest of the domain is covered?

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics app from cloudflare which is awesome and they manage it to cover everything even the error pages and I like that but there is one page and one page only that I don't want it to be covered. How can i stop the Google Analytics from monitoring it?

Comment: Please proper punctuation and capitalization. This isn't texting or chat.

Comment: so sorry Mr. John but English isn't my first language that's why i'm not that good at it and thank you so much for stopping by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to Google Analytics and select the view in question.

Top right click admin > filters > new filter > custom filter

You could use page title if it's a unique title - just enter the title in the filter text box.

Or you could filter the URL by typing in all or part of the URL.

Screen shot attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap your Google analytics code in a conditional statement pseudo php code using a page ID from a dynamic website. You may also use the current URL path in place of a page ID for static pages. This will prevent tracking code from firing on the page you do not want to track

```
<?php

$dt = 123; // The page ID if available of the page to NOT track

if($current_page_id != $dt){
...show analytics code
}
?>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, as Cloudflare adds the Google Analytics code independent of the server side. @Doug Firr is the way to go